# What is a word to describe a speech that is quick and continuously spoken without stopping?

Tags: word-request

What is a word to describe a speech that is quick and continuously spoken without stopping?

I need a word for this.

Comment: **Patter** is a word that is sometimes used, though it has the added connotation that the speech is probably well-rehearsed and intended to distract the listener.  Stage magicians and aggressive sales people are said to use **patter** to cover up their tricks.

Comment: @CanadianYankee -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Hmmm!  It seems to me there could be some pertinent technical terms from __auctioneering__ to describe what they do, but if so I don't know what they are.

Comment: Do you merely mean "speech that is quick and continuous", or do you mean "speech that is _uninterruptable_" and/or "speech that is _urgent_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "a speech," do you mean a speech as "He read a speech aloud to the gathered masses," or did you mean "a style of speaking"?

If you mean a speech that's given, I don't think that there's a word for what you're looking for. Perhaps a **rant** or even a **screed**, but the primary connotations of these words have nothing to do with what you asked for. The fact that a rant or a screed is typically spoken in a quick and uninterrupted style isn't really the main distinguishing feature of a rant or a screed.

If you meant "a style of speaking," I'm even less sure that there's a word to describe what you're looking for. Perhaps a phrase like "he had a **brisk** manner of speaking and spoke **without pause**."

Comment: For description of a style of vocal production, "Fluent and rapid".

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to make this an answer:  **patter** is quick, continuous speech that is *well-rehearsed* and *draws attention*.  Sometimes, it has the additional connotation of being deceitful or distracting, but that's not always the case.

A stage magician has **patter** that he uses to keep your attention away from his sleight of hand.

A salesman might have **patter** that he uses to keep your attention on the best parts of the product and perhaps keep you distracted so you don't ask inconvenient questions.

Where the word is used most often is in the sense of **patter song**, which is a song from an opera or a musical that has extremely fast, very evenly-delivered words.  The most famous patter song is [I Am the Very Model of a Modern Major General](https://youtu.be/zSGWoXDFM64?t=1m5s).  This is *not* deceitful or distracting, but obviously the singer has to be well-rehearsed to deliver this song.